# Kill a process if it exists

Tags: bash, shell, kill-process

I want to kill all instruments processes that are running.  I am using this:

`sudo killall instruments`

I am using this in a script and sometimes the process is not running and it stops my script saying there are no processes with that name that are running.

How can I check if a particular process is running? Instruments in my case.

Comment: `ps -ax|grep instruments|grep -v grep|wc -l` would be non-zero if there's a process with `instruments` in the name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
sudo killall instruments 2>/dev/null
```

isn't enough?

Comment: "killall" very useful =)

Answer (score 26):

If your script is terminating, you have most likely enabled `set -e`, to exit when a command fails.

If you don't care about the status, you can just append `|| true` to the command:

```
sudo killall instruments || true
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `pgrep <proc>` to search for a process named `<proc>`

```
if pgrep instruments &> /dev/null ; then sudo killall instruments ; fi
```

Comment: If you're using `pgrep`, might as well use `pkill`

Comment: @glennjackman of course, thanks!  I've just shown how one can search for a process, to kill a process by his name `killall` should suffice and the OP knows it.